# Configuration Checklist Contact Types

Tags: contact-types

Under Contact Types on the configuration checklist nothing appears - how do I get this back

Comment: You're looking at yoursite.com/civicrm/admin/options/subtype?reset=1 and there's nothing there?

Comment: Can you clarify: is it a totally blank screen or do you see the menus but no actual content ?